# How do I write an OR expression in Yii ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I tried the following, but it didn't work.

> $kw = \app\models\Keyword::find()->where(['keyword'=>$word, ['or', ['country' => $country], ['country' => null]], ['or', ['language' => $language], ['language' => null]]]);

I also tried

> $kw = \app\models\Keyword::find()->where(['keyword'=>$word, ['or', 'country' => $country, 'country' => null], ['or', 'language' => $language, 'language' => null]]);

Worthless error:

> PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'

Docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `...::find()->where(' keyword = :word or country = :country or language = :language ', ['word'=>'test', 'country'=>'US', 'language'=>'en'])` ?

Comment: Based on the doc you added, you might want to try `...::find()->where( [ 'or', ['keyword'=>$word], ['country' => $country], ['language' => $language] ] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with `andWhere()`

> $kw = \app\models\Keyword::find()->where(['keyword'=>$word])->andWhere(['or', ['country' => $country], ['country' => null]])->andWhere(['or', ['language' => $language], ['language' => null]]);

which yields

> SELECT * FROM `keyword` WHERE ((`keyword`='women\'s running shoes') AND ((`country`='US') OR (`country` IS NULL))) AND ((`language`='en') OR (`language` IS NULL)) ORDER BY `country`, `language`

Answer (score 0):

You can use *`orWhere()`* to do it:

```
$kw = \app\models\Keyword::find()->where(['keyword'=>$word])->orWhere(['country' => $country])->orWhere(['language' => $language]);
```

See this for more detail

www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#orWhere()-detaila

Comment: Are you sure? Because I'm sure that will add `where keyword = 'word' OR country = 'US' OR language = 'en'` which isn't exactly the same. The `keyword` MUST be present.

Comment: i'm sure you can add many condition as you want see the link.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `Keyword::find()` instead of `\app\models\Keyword::find()`
I had the similar problem. It worked fine for me. Hope it works for you too.